# Java, easiest way to identify if one week away or one month etc using dates

Tags: java, time

After 20 minutes of coding my attempt which was,
if given dd/mm/year and I have my current dd/mm/year, if 
the difference in years = 0, the difference in months = 0 and the difference in days = 7, then you're 1 week away.

Then I realized, this doesn't take into account date wrapping. For instance, if I'm given the date of 07/01/2017 and my current date is 06/29/2017. My algorithm would return false, but you're in fact less than 1 week away. (Depending on month as well, i.e. 30 or 31 days).

Therefore my question is, what is the easiest way to check if you're either:
1 month, two weeks or 1 week away from a date when

1. Given the date and
2. I am using the time given from `LocalDateTime.now()`

Comment: Have you looked through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) of the `LocalDate` class? It contains all the information you need to find a solution yourself

Comment: I'm given the date in the format of dd/mm/year. But localDate etc always print actual dates like April 04 etc,

Comment: @user7404408 You can use DateTimeFormatter (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) if you want to modify the output

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a 7 days

```
LocalDate old = LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 29);
LocalDate current = LocalDate.of(2017, 7, 1);

System.out.println(old.plusDays(7).isBefore(current));

old = LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 23);
System.out.println(old.plusDays(7).isBefore(current));
```

The output will be

```
false
true
```

Comment: Thanks                    15characters

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChronoUnit` to measure days/months/years/weeks between two dates

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of( 2017, 10, 10 );
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of( 2017, 11, 10 );

long years = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between( date1, date2 );
long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between( date1, date2 );
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( date1, date2 );
long weeks = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( date1, date2 );
```

Comment: Thanks                    15characters